# some keyboard button isnot working!

Tags: kernel, keyboard

"My laptop keyboard is not typing certain letters on Linux mint, but some keys are working. However, when I use an external keyboard, it only types the letters 'l,' 'a,' 'd,' 'k,' 'f,' and 's,' which are not working on the laptop keyboard."

Comment: Are these problems after installing Linux Mint?

Comment: yes. it is. i use mint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a Linux Mint Live USB/DVD and boot from it. Check if the keyboard works correctly in the live environment. If it does, it might indicate a keyboard layout configuration issue on your installed system.